# How to create a button which will have dynamic text length

Tags: html, css

I have to create a button styling for my website such that the button text will be dynamic content which I will either fetch from the database/user will enter .

What's the best way of designing it ? As of now I have designed it as an image at the left, next an image with repeat-x uptill the end of the text and then an image at the end. But , it does not look good .

Can you please upload a screenshot of some sample snapshot alongwith their style ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use CSS3 for whatever reason, I'd recommend utilizing the venerable "Sliding Doors" technique:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/

Comment: +1 as well. Sliding Doors versus CSS3... it all depends on what you need to support. But this is a great technique too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just style it with CSS? Here's an awesome site I've used, and all you'll have to do is give the text a class in order to style it.

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/